# Two different Div's have same ID and Class name which one is Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with a specific ID like: `id="1"`

I have another div in a different section of the class such as: `class="1"`.

I'm using the following jQuery to trigger my function, which should be really like onClick on ID div, action the other div which has the same ID has a class.

```
  $('#2').on('click', function(ev) {
      $(".video, .2")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
      ev.preventDefault();
    });
```

Which works perfectly. However, I would like to make this function dynamic. How?

Comment: You could use DOM traversal. We'd need to see the HTML to show you how to do that, though.

Comment: If two div ahve same Id, you make a mistake.An id must be unique, use class instead ?

Comment: Use dom traversal and get rid of the ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just get the id of the clicked element with `this.id` and concatenate it to the selector string. I would also use `attr("src", ...)` in this case to prevent JS errors in case there is no matching element in the page (or check for this condition if you'd still prefer vanilla JS).

```js
$('button[id]').on('click', function(ev) {
  var videoEl = $(".video ." + this.id);
  videoEl.attr("src", videoEl.attr("src") + "&autoplay=1");
  ev.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video"><video class="2" src="video.mp4?"></video></div>

<button id="2">autoplay video</button>
```

Comment: thing is i am going to have multiple div like that:

button id="1"
button id="2"
button id="3"

etc....

How can this be dynamic

Comment: `$('button[id]').on('click', ...)`

Comment: okay, and regarding the same clss to call at $(".video .2" + this.id) ?THanks a lot :)

Comment: I don't understand the question. What you've written now would assume that all the class names would start with the number "2" followed by the button ID.

Comment: owww no sory for the explanation then.

so if button has id 1, video has class="1"

if button has id="2", video has class="2"

if button has id="3", video has class="3" etc . . .

Comment: Yes, I understand, but you just wrote `$(".video .2" + this.id)`, so the "2" is redundant!

Comment: I updated my answer to include my first comment and to also respect the appending of the parameter instead of replacing the complete src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'HERE_A_SELECTOR_FOR_ALL_THE_ELEMENTS_WITH_IDn', function(ev) {
  $(".video ." + ev.target.id)[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
  ev.preventDefault();
});
```